# How to handle url.get() failure

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup

Good day everyone.

I have been developing an app that scrapes the data out of some tables on a website and displays them on screen. Everything works great but I want to put a redundancy in case there is no data connection. For example a dialog box or toast simply saying "No data connection".

How and where could I put this? Below is my Asynctask where jsoup gets the data so I was assuming I could put something in here?

At the moment the app crashes if there is no data connection to the website.

```
    //AsyncTask
private class Fixtures extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Fixtures");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            tables = doc.select("table");

            tablesSize = tables.size();

            for (int t = 0; t < (tables.size() - 1); t++){
                table = tables.get(t);
                rows = table.select("tr");
                date = doc.select("h2").get(t);
            }
        return null;
    }
```

Any help or a direction to other answers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it if your task is nested in a fragment you can just throw this method in the outer class. otherwise find a way to pass the applications context instead of using getActivity. This should be relatively thread safe.

```
private void buildFailedDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Could Not Connect to Site!");
    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Connection Failed");

    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

It might be better just to show a toast so that you don't disrupt the user from the activity

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to Connect to Site" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks Gabe. I think a toast will be sufficient, however where would I put it? If i put it in the catch the app still crashes. Do I need to do a null check on the doc or something? I just don't want the app to crash if it cannot reach the website.

Comment: Sorry I missed something. It was postExecute that was crashing. Fixed and implemented the toast correctly.